# How to use pop-up notifications in Django with Bulma?

Tags: django, django-views, bulma

I am making an app using Django, and I want to implement Bulma alerts, like this:

[image]

But, I can't figure out how. I need them to inform the user if they filled out a form correctly.

Does anyone know how to implement this?

Comment: user did signup on the web and after successful signup `Your account has been created` . notifications like this?